# Formatting Query for Use in Power Bi

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, powerbi

I am working on a dataset, which I intend to use for a power bi Chart, however I can't quite tailor it in the format required.
Basically I have the below dataset

[image]

Through the use of slicer for the sale start date and the dealer , I need to be able to group the month sold column and get a percentage of total sales per month. Not all records have a date sold so the idea is to get a percetnage per month of how many actually sold.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: You can't accomplish this with SQL. It's only possible with DAX.

Comment: @RADO if I group this in SQL then import as a dataset into powerbi can it not just plotted then ?

Comment: What are the numbers 1-11 in the report?

Comment: They are the month the sale was completed . You can see in my query above , I am getting the difference in months between the date it went on sale to the date it was actually sold . My goal is to create a line chart to show the percentage per month of sales in Power Bi

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that 1-11 is coming from the datediff calculation? If so, then building your chart should be quite simple. What's not working?

Comment: It is , however my issue is that the range of the months is not definitive and can change . So I basically need the bottom axis of my chart to range from 0 - the max number of months from my data set , and my y axis to be the percentage . Each month should be calculated as a percentage based on the total count of sales

Comment: I feel like I am missing something critically important here. Have you tried to build the chart? If yes, can you post the formulas you used for the % calculation?

Comment: I have tried , but my issue is including values on the x axis even if the count is 0 . I need my x axis to be a range from 0- the largest “month” number .

Comment: Hi @RADO , i believe I may have over complicated the explanation . I have altered the above which i believe makes it a lot clearer